# MongoDB SSL connection with self signed certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl, client-certificates

In the recent light of events of the MongoDB hacks. we too were hit by the hackers.

We enabled the authorization and changed the default port of the server.

However we want to encrypt our communication channel with the server with the help of a self signed certificate.

so our configuration looks like below

```
  tls:                                                                                                                                     
    mode: requireTLS                                                                                                                      
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false                                                                                            
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/server.pem                                                                                                
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.crt
```

what happens is when I try to connect the mongoshell with the client certificate the connection is constantly denied. But after commenting the CAFile config and using --tlsAllowInavlidCertificates the connection is created.

I created the certificate with the following link:
https://gist.github.com/kevinadi/96090f6f9973ff8c2d019bbe0d9a0f70

To connect to the server I'm using the following command:

`mongo --host hostname  --username user --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --port port --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile client.pem --tlsCAFile ca.crt`

I dont know what I'm doing wrong and is this the correct way to do it even?

Comment: The client certificate and the server certificate need to be issued by the same root certificate authority, so the server can validate the client certificate using its ca.crt.

Comment: thats whats i have done here i guess by following that link. single root CA is signing those certificates.

Comment: Try using openssl verify with the server's ca.crt and the client certificate. and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The server log contains reasons why connections are rejected.

Comment: The logs a quite sparse and doe not pin points the issue. this is what I got

Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate. Ending connection from <ip_address>

Comment: This means on one of the ends you don't have a CA certificate specified which matches the client certificate supplied by the other end. Unfortunately as you found out the message isn't generally helpful as to *which* end the problem is on, so generally you need to check both.